# Using posts and postmeta table to store custom Address Book Plugin data

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-field, database

On close inspection of WP, I realize that almost all the information is in the table `posts` and `postmeta`.

Do you think we should follow this example and put all our information in these table `posts` & `postmeta`?

I am creating a plugin "Address Book", do I need to create a new table `wp_addressbook` or do I insert my address book in the table `posts` (will I have to choose the fields)?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of "putting everything" in the `posts` table?

Answer (score 5):

### Using `posts` & `postmeta`:

There is nothing wrong in using `posts` and `postmeta` table for custom database requirements.

In WordPress, although `posts` & `postmeta` table was originally there to create blog posts, later it evolved to cover many different sorts of database requirements. Using [Custom Post Types](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/), [Post Meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/managing-post-metadata/) & [Custom Taxonomies](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomies/working-with-custom-taxonomies/), you can satisfy most database requirements generally used in web development.

In your case, you may use [Custom Post Types](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/) (for address book), [Post Meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/managing-post-metadata/) (for custom address book fields) & [Custom Taxonomies](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomies/working-with-custom-taxonomies/) (for custom categorization or grouping of address book entries).

**Advantage:**

- You'll be able to use tried and tested WordPress core functions to manage the data.
- Tons of Plugins & Themes will support this, so you'll be able to use them to enhance your development further.

**Disadvantage:**

- The database will not be 100% tidy, i.e. there will be redundant columns.
- DB query may not be 100% optimized (may be 99%) compared to a custom DB structure.

Check [WordPress Database structure](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) to make a more informed decision.

### Creating custom DB structure:

You really don't need to create custom DB tables for this. However, if you feel necessary, you may [follow this doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins).

**Advantage**:

- You may design a 100% tidy relational DB structure, i.e. no redundancy.
- You may optimize 100% to your heart's content.

**Disadvantage**:

- You'll have to spend a ton of time to apply all the security, efficiency & usability measures already taken care of in WordPress core and many useful optimization related plugins.
- Available plugin & theme compatibility will be difficult to maintain.
- All the time spent may not worth the little benefit you may or may not gain.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your reply and your clarification.
I think I'll use the tables "posts ..."
Thank you so much for your help and time.

cordially

Comment: You are welcome @Acquatella. Now please select this as accepted answer so that other people with similar question may find it easily in the future.